# Wrap text observations in a column

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataframe and this column contains text data separated by ;

```
 x1 =c ("Anal Exam Under ;", "Sigmoidoscopy;Colonoscopy; Esophagogastroduodenoscopy;" ,"Fistula                  
 Repair;Percutaneous Endo. G-Tube (PEG);" ,"Sigmoidoscopy;Anorectal Motility/Anorectal Manometry 
 (ARMS);","Sigmoidoscopy;Colonoscopy;", "Procedure; Auditory Brain Stem ;", "Colonoscopy; EGD 
 (Endoscopy Upper GI);", "Eye Exam; Lumbar Puncture; MRI Scan;
 EGD (Endoscopy Upper GI);", "EUS Upper GI (Endoscopic Ultrasound); Sigmoidoscopy;")

 x1
 [1] "Anal Exam Under ;"                                              
 [2] "Sigmoidoscopy;Colonoscopy; Esophagogastroduodenoscopy;"         
 [3] "Fistula Repair;Percutaneous Endo. G-Tube (PEG);"                
 [4] "Sigmoidoscopy;Anorectal Motility/Anorectal Manometry (ARMS);"   
 [5] "Sigmoidoscopy;Colonoscopy;"                                     
 [6] "Procedure; Auditory Brain Stem ;"                               
 [7] "Colonoscopy; EGD (Endoscopy Upper GI);"                         
 [8] "Eye Exam; Lumbar Puncture; MRI Scan;\nEGD (Endoscopy Upper GI);"
 [9] "EUS Upper GI (Endoscopic Ultrasound); Sigmoidoscopy;"
```

How do i make the text wrap to a new line (not new row) , new line, within that cell whenever it encounters an ;

For example the second and third observations are

```
  [2] "Sigmoidoscopy;Colonoscopy; Esophagogastroduodenoscopy;"
  [3] "Fistula Repair;Percutaneous Endo. G-Tube (PEG);"
```

and I want it to look like

```
  [2] "Sigmoidoscopy;Colonoscopy; 
       Esophagogastroduodenoscopy;"
  [3] "Fistula Repair;
       Percutaneous Endo. G-Tube (PEG);"
```

Need some help doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gsub()` to replace all instances of `;` with leading and trailing white space.

Try this:

```
z <- gsub(" *; *\n* *", "\n", x1)
cat(z)
```

Results in

```
Anal Exam Under
 Sigmoidoscopy
Colonoscopy
Esophagogastroduodenoscopy
 Fistula                  
 Repair
Percutaneous Endo. G-Tube (PEG)
 Sigmoidoscopy
Anorectal Motility/Anorectal Manometry 
 (ARMS)
 Sigmoidoscopy
Colonoscopy
 Procedure
Auditory Brain Stem
 Colonoscopy
EGD 
 (Endoscopy Upper GI)
 Eye Exam
Lumbar Puncture
MRI Scan
EGD (Endoscopy Upper GI)
 EUS Upper GI (Endoscopic Ultrasound)
Sigmoidoscopy
```